# Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, sinatra, sequel

When I am trying to migrate files using command prompt:
`sequel -m db/migrations/ mysql://root:root@localhost/todo`
 I get the following error:

> Error: Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: cannot load such file --
>   mysql
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'

Below is my migration file in db/migrations:

```
    Sequel.migration do
     change do
        create_table :users do
        primary_key :id
        String :name, :unique => true, :length => 32, :null => false
        String :password, :length => 32, :null => false
        DateTime :created_at
     end
   end
end
```

My gemfile:

```
>     GEM   remote: https://rubygems.org/   specs:
>     rack (2.0.3)
>     rack-protection (2.0.0)
>       rack
>     sinatra (2.0.0)
>       rack (~> 1.4)
>       rack-protection (~> 1.4)
>       tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
>     tilt (2.0.7)
> 
> PLATFORMS   x64-mingw32
> 
> DEPENDENCIES   bundler (= 1.15.1)   sinatra (= 2.0.0)
> 
> BUNDLED WITH
>    1.15.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `mysql2` adapter for your connection string. That also means you have to install the `mysql2` gem on your machine. Make sure you have the MySQL development package on your machine and build essentials since this gem is a native extension and has dependencies outside Ruby.

Then connect via:

```
sequel -m db/migrations/ mysql2://root:root@localhost/todo
```

Comment: 5 years to collect your reward. well deserved too!

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I had a `mysql://` . Using a `mysql2` fixed it.